# dd-wrt router crashes during big uploads, downloads are perfect

Tags: networking, router, internet, dd-wrt

I download about 300GB monthly in big months and it’s always perfectly fine and router has uptimes of months, but when I start uploading a few gigabytes of data via FTP or via vSphere, the router usually crashes after a while, pretty much always before 2GB is uploaded.

I am not 100% sure if it’s the router that crashes, because when I disable and re-enable my network connection, the internet connection works perfectly fine again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log into your DDWRT via SSH/Telnet
then 'cat /var/log/messages | grep dropping'

see if you come up with any dropped packages..

check out some of the other diagnostics here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Router_Slowdown

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately my dd-wrt does not log.

Comment: try to turn on loggin and then wait for it to happen again